# How can I handle this compilation error through exception?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How can I handle this compilation error through exception?

```
declare
table_or_view_does_not_exist exception;
pragma exception_init(table_or_view_does_not_exist,-00942);
b exception;
pragma exception_init(b,-00942);
d_table varchar2(200);
c_table varchar2(200);
c_count Number;
begin
    begin
        d_table:='drop table audit_table PURGE';
        execute immediate d_table;
        exception
            when table_or_view_does_not_exist then
                null;
                end;
                <<lable>>
             c_table := 'create table audit_table
             (table_name varchar2(50),
             column_name varchar2(50),
             count_type varchar2(50),
             v_count number)';
             execute immediate c_table;
select count(*) into c_count from customer_profile where cust_id is null;
insert into audit_table columns (table_name,column_name,count_type,v_count) values('customer_profile','cust_id','null','c_count');
 exception
 when b then
 GOTO lable;
 end;
```

Error report:

> ORA-06550: line 25, column 13:
> PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
>
> ORA-06550: line 25, column 1:
> PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>
> ORA-06550: line 28, column 2:
> PLS-00375: illegal GOTO statement; this GOTO cannot branch to label 'LABLE'
>
> ORA-06550: line 28, column 2:
> PL/SQL: Statement ignored
> 06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
> *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
> *Action:

Comment: Exception handling is for runtime errors only: [*This chapter explains how to handle PL/SQL compile-time warnings and **PL/SQL runtime errors. The latter are called exceptions.***](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-error-handling.html#GUID-0502DC1A-F0A5-4180-A912-6A5CDC855F56). So you need to use dynamic SQL for all statements that access possibly absent objects

Comment: Can I suggest aligning your code neatly, so that `declare`-`begin`-`exception`-`end` keywords for the same block are indented the same amount etc. This will make it much easier to understand and maintain your code, as well as making some errors easier to spot.

Answer (score 3):

What you do, is just *bad practice*. In Oracle, we don't create tables in PL/SQL but at SQL level and then use them in our procedures.

In your case, you'd

```
-- create table first
create table audit_table ...;

-- use it in PL/SQL procedure
declare
  ...
begin
  ...
  insert into audit_table ...
end;
/
```

---

You can't "handle" compilation error through exception. What you could do is to put `insert` statement into dynamic SQL. Also, it wouldn't harm if you used valid syntax (there's no `columns` "keyword" there).

```
execute immediate q'[insert into audit_table 
                     (table_name, column_name, count_type, v_count)
                     values('customer_profile', 'cust_id', 'null', :a)]'
                  using c_count;
```

but - once again - that's just bad practice. Don't do it that way, there's no benefit and many disadvantages.

As of `goto` - well, jumping around your code is almost always wrong. Error you got says that you can't jump out of the exception handler so your *idea* was wrong anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Could you consider another way to control the flow - comments in the code:

```sql
DECLARE
    cmd         VarChar2(200);
    c_count     Number(6);
    --
    Status      VarChar2(255);
BEGIN
    cmd :='drop table audit_table';
    Begin   -- 1st nested PL/SQL block
        Execute Immediate cmd;
        Status := 'OK';
    Exception                   -- this could be raised if  the table doesn't exist which is probably OK
            When OTHERS Then
                Status := 'OK'; -- SQLERRM = ORA-00942: table or view does not exist - nothing happens - it would be droped anyway
                -- Status := 'ERR - ' || SQLERRM;   -- this is alternative if you want to do something else with this ERR
    End;
    If Status != 'OK' Then  -- here you can check the status and decide what to do
        GoTo EndIt;
    End If;
    --
  <<lable>>  -- in this code there is no need for this label
    cmd :=  'create table audit_table (table_name varchar2(50), column_name varchar2(50), count_type varchar2(50), v_count number)';
    Begin   -- 2nd nested PL/SQL block
        Execute Immediate cmd;
        Status := 'OK';
    Exception
            When OTHERS Then
                Status := 'ERR - ' || SQLERRM;
    End;
    If Status != 'OK' Then  -- here you can check the status and decide what to do
        dbms_output.putline(Status);    -- send error message and exit - there is no audit_table
        GoTo EndIt;
    Else
        Null;    -- here you can do something else (if maybe the table already exists)
    End If;
    --
    -- think about what could go wrong below (2 lines) and either leave it as it is or put it in the 3rd nested PL/SQL block
    Select count(*) Into c_count From customer_profile Where cust_id Is Null;
    insert into audit_table (table_name, column_name, count_type, v_count) values('customer_profile', 'cust_id', 'Null', c_count);

  <<EndIt>>     -- used to end the block if needed
    Null;
EXCEPTION
        When OTHERS Then
            dbms_output.putline(SQLERRM);   -- You can not get out of here since it is main PL/SQL blok that went into an exception
END;
```

**Addition**

Below is an option of basic steps to do the job (3rd block) without compilation errors. I have no possibility to check it out so please do it yourself (there could be some syntax problem or something else). The goal is to be sure that you can insert the record...

I declared `sq` variable to construct insert command and the end of the code above could be (please check the command yourself - I can't test it right now) something like here:

```sql
DECLARE
    ...
    sq          VarChar2(1) := '''';   -- this is single-quote character
    ...
BEGIN
    ...
    ...
    --
    -- think about what could go wrong below (2 lines) and either leave it as it is or put it in the 3rd nested PL/SQL block
    Select count(*) Into c_count From customer_profile Where cust_id Is Null;
    cmd := 'insert into audit_table (table_name, column_name, count_type, v_count) values(' || sq || 'customer_profile' || sq || ', ' || sq || 'cust_id' || sq || ', ' || sq || 'Null' || sq || ', ' || c_count || ')';
    Begin   -- 3rd nested PL/SQL block
        Select Count(*) Into c_count From all_tables Where table_name = 'audit_table' and owner = 'your_table_owner'; -- check if table exist - if it doesn't set Status
        If c_count = 1 Then     -- if table exists then you can insert the record
            Execute Immediate cmd;
            Status := 'OK';     -- all done
        Else
            Status := 'ERR';
        End If;
    Exception
            When OTHERS Then
                Status := 'ERR - ' || SQLERRM;  -- catch error and pass it to the main block
    End;
    If Status != 'OK' Then  -- here you can check the status and decide what to do
        dbms_output.putline(Status);    -- send error message and exit - there is no audit_table -->> OR DO SOMETHING ELSE
        GoTo EndIt;
    Else
        Null;    -- here you can do something else if you wish
    End If;
    --
  <<EndIt>>     -- used to end the block if needed
    Null;
EXCEPTION
        When OTHERS Then
            dbms_output.putline(SQLERRM);   -- You can not get out of here since it is main PL/SQL blok that went into an exception
END;
```

Comment: Brother your code is giving same error, you did not understand my code that why i was using exception after insert statement because when my code will execute first time , it will drop and even create table if table is not there in database then my exception will be used after drop statement , but in pre compilation , what oracle is doing , it checks insert statement first then drop and create statement is being checked in pre compilation and it gives error at insert statement because it is not finding any table in database. how can i handle error in this type of situation that is my point?

Comment: @Aman As I said in the code - it is on you to think about 3rd block to handle this. First and second are here to give you idea how. I can't test it in my db, sorry. You can check (using Status) if there is a table or not, how many records are there (if any) etc.etc...

Comment: @Aman Put insert in the 3rd block, try to prevent exception - if you can't use exception (in 3rd block) to catch the error - pass it to main block using Status - and in main block decide what is the next step.... Exception in the main block is THE END - there is no way back.

Comment: @Aman Just posted the Addition

Answer (score 0):

You actually ***can*** trap compilation errors, by wrapping the whole block in an execute immediate so compilation is postponed until runtime. But that's *not* the right way to go.

Your real issue is that you are referring to the object you are dynamically dropping/creating as a hard-coded dependency of your PL/SQL block:

```
insert into audit_table ... -- this is a hard dependency
```

You can't compile PL/SQL if hard dependencies don't exist until run time. If you really must dynamically drop/recreate the table (and I agree with the above reviewer that this is architecturally questionable), you must also make this insert dynamic as well in order to break the dependency chain:

```
execute immediate 'insert into audit_table values (:col1, :col2, :col3, :col4)' using 'customer_profile','cust_id','null','c_count'; -- this creates no dependency
```

That will prevent Oracle from creating an object dependency on this table so your code can compile even though the table does not exist at compile time.

But once again, please be sure this is the right technique. There are only a few rare cases where this actually makes good architectural sense. Oh, and please remove the GOTO and label junk. We really don't use that in modern languages; they create unmanageable spaghetti code.